# Code Igniter controller pages

Tags: codeigniter, controller

How can I make an controller, which will be accessible on the following url address:

```
/index.php/my_controller/controller_function/another_function
```

or

```
/index.php/account/profile/edit
```

I know that is possible, but I cant find any site which will explain this, from the manual I've read that the controller should be in the folder, but what then?

Comment: Shall it be accessible from both of them (if so, I'd suggest using "AND", not "OR" in your question ;) ) ? Have you looked at http://www.codeigniter.fr/user_guide/general/routing.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a controller called `class Account extends CI_Controller`, which has the method `profile`, taking a parameter of `$action` - this will automatically be filled with `edit` when you visit `/account/profile/edit`.

```
public function profile ($action = '')
{
    switch ($action)
    {
        case 'edit':
            $this->show_edit_account();
        break;

        default:
            $this->show_default_action();
        break;
    }
}

protected function show_edit_account ()
{
    echo 'Edit account!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Joe's answer, I find my code easier to organize when I just have a controller function mapped directly to what I see in the URL path instead of calling other functions. Depending on how much you plan to do within your account class, it could be a mess to maintain from this single controller. So if all you are trying to do is achieve that particular URL structure, you can nest your controller within a sub-folder in CodeIgniter's controllers folder.

So `/index.php/account/profile/edit` would map to `/application/controllers/account/profile.php` and `edit` would be a function within `profile.php`. This way, you can also maintain separate controllers for different functions within account. e.g. in addition to profile, you could make a separate `delete.php` controller to handle account deletions.

You can read more on how CodeIgniter maps URLs to controllers, functions, and variables in the manual: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html